# Arduino serial port eats data for 3 seconds before it sends?

Tags: serial

With the source code below, I'm getting what I think to be strange behaviour with the serial port output.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

int c = 0;    
void loop() {
  Serial.println(c++);
}
```

Presumably what this will do is starting printing incrementing numbers, one on each line, starting from 0. However, my serial monitor only starts printing these numbers after the 3000 mark. I found this behaviour only after discovered in another sketch that I was losing data at the beginning.

Is this normal Arduino behaviour? Or a serial monitor problem? Or something else?

Comment: Is it consistent? Does it always begin at 3000? And does it continue as expected (3001,3002,...) after that?

Comment: There are many Arduino models. It helps considerably to state in the question which one you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a Leonardo or Yun?  If it is, you have to wait until the `Serial` object says the USB connection is really ready:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB
}
```

Read [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/IfSerial).

Because you did't wait, your `loop` is able to execute 3000 times before `Serial` actually sends something back to the PC.